# React Typescript - Add more elements from a string array to useState array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, arraylist, use-state, react-typescript

Is there a way to push or add more elements to useState Array using a a new string array? I am able to add only a single string using the function below. I tried looping the string array and updating but it appears to only update `initialList.list` when the last element. I need all the elements in string array to be pushed to `initialList.list`

```
const [initialList, setinitialList] = useState({ listName: "List 1", list: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'] });


let multiElements:string[] = ['Four', 'Five', 'Six']

        multiElements.forEach(e => {
          setinitialList({
            listName: initialList.listName,
            list: [...initialList.list, e]
          })
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could use a callback for the setter instead:

```
setinitialList(initialList => ({
```

It'd make more sense to combine the arrays with `concat`, just once, instead of calling the state setter so many times synchronously:

```
setinitialList({
  ...initialList,
  list: initialList.list.concat(multiElements)
});
```

Personally, I'd also suggest separating out the states - these are using hooks, after all, not class state:

```
const [list, setList] = useState(['One', 'Two', 'Three']);
const [listName, setListName] = useState("List 1");
```

Then you'll just have to do

```
setList(list.concat(multiElements);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access to the previous state, you want to pass it a function which takes the previous value as a parameter. See the [React Hooks API docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

```
const [initialList, setInitialList] = useState({
  listName: 'List 1',
  list: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
});

// You don't need to type the variable here - TypeScript can infer it
const multiElements: string[] = ['Four', 'Five', 'Six'];

setInitialList((prevState) => ({
  listName: initialList.listName,
  list: [...prevState.list, ...multiElements],
}));
```

The key here is spreading the previous state and also spreading the `multiElements` that you want to add to the array.